# HttpUrlConnection addRequestProperty Method Not Passing Parameters

Tags: java, post, parameters, httpurlconnection

I have some working java code which does the following:

```
URL myUrl = new URL("http://localhost:8080/webservice?user=" + username + "&password=" + password + "&request=x");

HttpURLConnection myConnection = (HttpURLConnection) myUrl.openConnection();
myConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");

// code continues to read the response stream
```

However, I noticed that my webserver access log contained the plaintext password for all of the users who connected. I would like to get this out of the access log, but the webserver admins claim that this needs to be changed in my code and not via webserver config.

I tried changing the code to the following:

```
URL myUrl = new URL("http://localhost:8080/webservice");

HttpURLConnection myConnection = (HttpURLConnection) myUrl.openConnection();
myConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
// start of new code
myConnection.setDoOutput(true);
myConnection.addRequestProperty("username", username);
myConnection.addRequestProperty("password", password);
myConnection.addRequestProperty("request", "x");

// code continues to read the response stream
```

Now the access log does not contain the username/password/request method. However, the webservice now throws an exception indicating that it didn't receive any username/password.

What did I do wrong in my client code? I also tried using "setRequestProperty" instead of "addRequestProperty" and it had the same broken behavior.

Answer (score 7):

I actually found the answer in [another question on stackoverflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4206094/1535124)

The correct code should be:

```
URL myUrl = new URL("http://localhost:8080/webservice");

HttpURLConnection myConnection = (HttpURLConnection) myUrl.openConnection();
myConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
myConnection.setDoOutput(true);

DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(myConnection.getOutputStream ());
wr.writeBytes("username=" + username + "&password="+password + "&request=x");

// code continues to read the response stream
```

Comment: You should validate your answer ;-)

Comment: Jones and david can you tell me that can i send image as u sending username and passsword?? see my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27615276/how-to-send-data-to-server

Comment: all the posts on here i have searched that are almost exactly the same and yours solves my problem, thank you David!