# Add header to (HTTP request for) file download

Tags: android, android-4.3-jelly-bean

Working from an example, I use the following code to download a file:

```
url = new URL(stUrl);
connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

connection.addRequestProperty ("Foo", "Bar");
connection.setDoOutput(true);    // update as per comment!
connection.connect();

        // download the file
is = new BufferedInputStream(
    url.openStream(),
    8192
);
os = new BufferedOutputStream( new FileOutputStream( tmp ) );
copyStream( is, os );
```

This works fine for downloading. But including the `Foo/Bar`header in the http request fails.

Why?

---

**updates**:

- Download url = "http://x0data.com/android/default/rqst"
- I want to pass headers (not GET or POST parameters)
- I know the server is OK, because this used to work (for Android code that I seem to have lost...)

Comment: What is in the url? How does it look like?

Comment: I have added the URL. But note that the downloading if the file works fine. The problem is the header is not being included.

Comment: The header is not received by the server? So all depends on the server as you are not specifying that configuration zip. So what kind of server code /script is answering the 'request'?

Comment: Do you want to pass headers or parameters?

Comment: Isn't it this what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15551676/httpurlconnection-addrequestproperty-method-not-passing-parameters

Comment: @greenapps: Yes, that SO-link is exactly what I want. Except that in my case, it does not work. Something seems to go wrong between `addRequestProperty` and reading the response stream.

Comment: Then you did not understand why i posted that link. It does not work for the poster there too. Look at the answer of @David if you want to send parameters.

Comment: I read @David. I also added the `connection.setDoOutput(true);` But Android is still not sending my header. It must be something to do with `BufferedInputStream` (?)

Answer (score 1):

OK, with some great help from @greenapps. The following seems include headers while downloading a file:

```
url = new URL(stUrl);
connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.addRequestProperty ("Foo", "Bar");
connection.setDoOutput(true);

OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
writer.flush();

String line;
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
```

Now, I just need to figure how to write a `BufferedReader` to a `File`...

(and test & verify...)